# date picker opens to select option in ionic

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

i have created a filter to a history page of my application.my filter works fine in the first attempt but after the first attempt when i try to click on a select option field it opens a date picker. (my next field has a date picker and i think the focus goes automatically to that field when i click on my select option). How can i fix this?

my filter code

```
<script id="image-modal.html" type="text/ng-template">

      <div class="centered" >

      <ion-item style="width:290px;height:350px;" >

      <div class="closeButton">
      <a class="icon-right button-small button-clear ion-ios7-close-outline" style="float:right;"ng-click="modal.hide();"></a>
      </div>
      <div>
      <h2 > Filter Search </h2>
      </div>





      <label class="item item-input custom-input-label item-stacked-label " >
      <span class="input-label" >Account :</span><br>
      <select style="width:100%;" id="filterAcc" ng-model="filter.acc" ng-options="account.account for account in accountsArr" >
      <option id="default" value="" selected="selected">--Select Account--</option>
      </select>
      </label>


      <label class="item item-input custom-input-label item-stacked-label ">
      <span class="input-label" >From :</span><br>
      <input type="date" id="fromDate" name="input" ng-model="filter.fromDate"
      placeholder="Select From Date" required />
      </label>



      <label class="item item-input custom-input-label item-stacked-label ">
      <span class="input-label" >To :</span><br>
      <input type="date" id="toDate" name="input" ng-model="filter.toDate"
      placeholder="Select To Date" required />
      </label>



        <div class="col" style="padding=true;">
      <button class="button button-small button-positive"  style="display: inline-block;width:100px;margin-left:50px;" ng-click="modal.hide(); filter(filter);">Filter</button>

      </div>

      </ion-item>
      </div>
      </script>
```

This how it appears when i click on select option for the second time
[image]

Comment: If make a plnkr that shows this is might be easier to figure out

Comment: it's ok i figured out the issue.thank you for the concern

Comment: @CraZyDroiD do you mind posting the solution how you figured this out ?